# Why `auth.logout && auth.logout();` in the following example?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I am looking at the angular authentication application at https://codepen.io/aronrodrigues/pen/YXvBWW. But I don't understand what is happening with the statement `auth.logout && auth.logout();` on line 102 of the js file. Why does it appear to be calling `auth.logout` twice?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but in JavaScript the first `auth.logout` doesn't actually call the function. It will return the function itself, making sure that the function only gets called (the second `auth.logout()`) if it actually exists.

Comment: Oh! Is that really necessary? Or is that a standard practice... meaning that I should ALWAYS be checking for whether the method exists before calling it. What happens if I just call the method directly?

Comment: Nothing will happen, as long as the method exists. If it doesn't, you'll get an error and all of the JS on your page will stop working as a result. In an Angular application, that would be more problematic than most other places.

Comment: But that's true for any method.. isn't it? So does that mean I should always be checking for the existence before calling any method? I have to admit that I haven't seen it done much...

Comment: Neither have I, it seems a bit odd to me.